# processing string in firebase functions

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am having Trouble in processing string in firebase functions here is my code :

index.js:

```
exports.findemail = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    let email = data.params.Email
    const cityRef = db.collection('Users').doc(email.toString());
    const doc = await cityRef.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document! '+email.toString());
      //  resp.send('No Data' +email.toString());
        return "No DATA : "+email.toString();
    } else {
        //console.log('data present', doc.data());
        console.log('Data Present For : '+email);
        return "DATA ! : "+email.toString();
    }
});
```

MainActiviy:

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Task<String> taskData = callCloudFunction();
                taskData.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                        textView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s", taskData.getResult()));
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        textView.setText(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

   private Task<String> callCloudFunction() {
        FirebaseFunctions mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
        Object email_find = editText.getText().toString();
       // String textti = editText.getText().toString();
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("Email",email_find);
        return mFunctions
                .getHttpsCallable("findemail")
                .call(data)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                        return (String) task.getResult().getData();
                    }
                });
  }
```

the string is undefined

[image]

It works when i pass text manually by "askjfk@gmail.com", but it wont work when i call it using gettext from edittext. I am able to pass string, but cat process it to set doc path.

Answer (score 0):

Given that if you set manually the `String` it works, and according to [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) in the documentation:

```
private Task<String> addMessage(String text) {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("text", text);
    data.put("push", true);
...
}
```

You can retrieve the text as `String` and set it as it in the `Map<>`: Use this

```
String email_find = editText.getText().toString();
```

instead of:

```
Object email_find = editText.getText().toString();
```